# not able to include one html file in another

Tags: html

a.html

```
ABC
```

b.html

```
    <!--#include FILE="a.html" --> 

XYZ
```

access b.html: file:///home/kurz/Desktop/b.html

it only shows `XYZ`

is this not the way to include files in html?

Comment: which platform? I think its platform dependent.

Comment: you can also safely forget about this problem and move on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're attempting is called a [Server-Side Include](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) (SSI). As such, it requires the pages be running on a webserver, rather than a local file.

When you're requesting the page from a server, the server sees the `<!--#include FILE="a.html" -->` preprocessor and performs the SSI.

When you're referencing it directly from your filesystem, such as `file:///home/kurz/Desktop/b.html`, all your browser is doing is loading the raw html and interpreting that.

Comment: Not only does it need to run on a webserver, the server has to support SSI and be configured to look for SSI directives in the page being viewed.

Answer (score 0):

If it's apache try

```
<!--#include virtual="insertthisfile.html" -->
```

From [here](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/include.html):

> include virtual and include file do
>   almost the same thing. The difference
>   is that include virtual takes a
>   URL-style path, which is what you
>   probably expect. include virtual can
>   also execute CGI programs, if your web
>   server supports that, and include
>   their output. include file takes a
>   file-system path, and cannot execute
>   CGI programs. Both also accept
>   relative paths, so for a simple case
>   like the above they work the same. If
>   you don't understand the difference
>   between web paths and file system
>   paths, use include virtual.

Answer (score 0):

The one you are doing is `SSI` -> `Server Side Includes` which requires `Apache` or `IIS` to work.

You need to install `Apache` (for windows / unix) or `IIS` (for windows) for this to work. Also, you can test this on remote webservers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, servers are required for server side includes

If its just plain HTML, use iframes...
instead of a #include, use :

```
<iframe src="a.html"></iframe>
```

If your site is to be XHTML compliant (probably not).. you would need to make further changes

Comment: iframes are as much as part of XHTML as they are HTML